# How to deploy Spark2 Job via Yarn REST API

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-2.0

Although there are some examples (and [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733953/yarn-rest-api-spark-job-submission)) on how to submit Spark-Jobs via the YARN-REST-API, there are none, that address the specific changes required to make it work with Spark2. I'm currently basing my work off [this example](https://github.com/bernhard-42/spark-yarn-rest-api) and [accompanying documentation](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/28070/starting-spark-jobs-directly-via-yarn-rest-api.html), but one thing already is quite clear: Spark2 no longer requires a Spark-assembly jar on HDFS, as far as I can tell. Instead on HDP, there's a spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz deployed in HDFS.

Now, I wonder how I would have to configure the local-resources in am-container-spec to make the container Spark2 compatible:

- How would I build the classpath for REST-compatbility (in particular `__spark.jar__`)?
- Can I reduce the overall amount of duplicate configuration (as suggested [here, for the Java YARN-API](http://blog.hgadgil.com/data-engineering/submit-spark2-jobs-programmatically/))?